# How to get the last element of a Collection Navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public class Personel  
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public ICollection<Agreement> Agreements { set; get;}
}

public class Agreement
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
}
```

I have a domain model as above and have a dbcontext.

How do I get the last Agreement?

```
var result = _db.Personels.Include(a=>a.Agreements).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

**I want to get all the personels and last agreement of them...**

This gives me all the agreement of a personel, i want only the last one ordered by id descending.

Comment: Why can't you just use `.Last()` from `Linq`?

Comment: I want to get all personels and the last agreement of them.

Comment: you may select anonymous type where each on represents `personel` and another its `lastAgreement`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 
from p in _db.Personels
select new {
        personel = p,
        lastAgreement = p.Agreements.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()
       }
.ToList();
```

Now you can convert this to list of `Personels` and set `lastAgreement` for each of those.

Comment: I want to get all the personels and last agreements of them

Comment: This gives me last personel, not all the personels with their last agreement

Comment: ok, that can be done with linq, moment